# What happens on a critically failed secret check while camping in "Age of Ashes - Cult of Cinders"?

Tags: campaign-settings, pathfinder-2e

I have a question concerning the Camp in the Mwangi Jungle activity taking place during the exploration of the jungle in the part 2 Cult of Cinders of the Age of Ashes campaign.

The activity is described below:

> Setting up a camp in the Mwangi Jungle takes about an hour and requires one PC to attempt a secret  DC  22  Survival  check  to  determine  the  quality  of  the  campsite.  Utilizing  Ekujae  mosquito  netting  they  provide  grants  the  PC  a  +2  circumstance  bonus  to  this  Survival  check.  At  your  option,  other  precautions  taken  by  the  PCs  can  instead  grant  this  bonus,  but  multiple  tactics  are  not  cumulative. Certain magic spells like magnificent mansion or rope trick, or magic items  like  an  instant  fortress,  can  create  shelters  that  result  in  an  automatic  success at camping in dangerous terrain like the Mwangi Jungle, but at this point in their adventuring careers, the PCs are unlikely to have access to this type of magic. This activity assumes the PCs are resting for 8 hours.

> **Critical  Success**  The  camp  serves  the  PCs  well,  allowing  them  to  rest  and  make  their  daily  preparations  upon  waking  without  difficulty.  The  camp  is  also  camouflaged  or  protected,  and  as  a  result,  there  is  no  chance  of  a  random  encounter while the PCs rest.

> **Success**  The  camp  serves  the  PCs  well,  allowing  them  to  rest  and  make  their  daily preparations upon waking without difficulty.

> **Failure** The camp doesn’t effectively prevent insects, rain, and other unpleasant jungle elements from reaching the PCs. The PCs can still rest and make their daily preparations, but each PC is also exposed to dysentery (see sidebar).

> **Critical Failure** The camp is an utter mess. The PCs are exposed to both dysentery and  malaria  (see  sidebar).  In  addition,  they  gain  no  benefit  from  rest  during  the time spent camping, and they instead become fatigue.

I'm not sure what are the rules for the **critical failure** when it's written "they  gain  no  benefit". I guess they do not regain any HP. But what about spell and focus spell slots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm putting the entire answer in spoilers, since describing this process will necessarily reveal what it is we are talking about.

> The rules for resting are found on page 480 of the Core Rulebook. Benefits of resting include:

> ```
> - Regaining HP (Constitution modifier*level)
> - Improving certain conditions, such as fatigued.
> - Daily preparations require being rested.
> ```

> Daily preparations include quite a few things. This is when spellcasters regain spell slots and prepared casters choose their daily spells. Focus points refresh at this time. Magical items are invested. And characters don armor and other items. Without time to prepare in the morning, none of these are done. Armor and equipment can be donned later by spending time, but many of the magical options can only be performed during daily preparations.